# Span with contenteditable attribute won't behave as an inline element in IE11

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I am having two `span` elements inside a `div` that has limited width.
The text content of the two merge seamlessly into one continuous "paragraph".

However, I need the second `span` to be a `contenteditable="true"`.

But when I add the attribute, the text of the second element starts from a new line in IE11.

```html
<div style="width:200px">
  <span>4.5</span> <span contenteditable="true">Test this simple layout in IE11 and see the wonders of the internet!</span>
</div>
```

Here is the JsFiddle for you to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/enoq0xk3/

Is there any known fix for that?

Comment: Old and known problem, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36862119/10283047 - not sure if any workaround exists though.

Comment: Hm... Eihter DuckDuckGo has a problem searching or my eyes missed this result. Searching directly on SO, I seem to give more results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662990/inline-contenteditable-tags-fail-to-align-correctly-in-ie

Comment: hey, can you try this solution..
this will change layout but it is working in IE too.
`<div style="width:200px; display:inline-block;">
  <span style="float:left;;">4.5</span> <span style="float:left; width:calc(100% - 22px);" contenteditable="true">Test this simple layout in IE11 and see the wonders of the internet!</span>
</div>`

Comment: @sbrrk No, that has two problems: the 2nd line does not start from the beginning of the area and I don't know in advance the width of the first element.

Comment: I don't want to bash DuckDuckGo, but virtually all other search engines yield more relevant results than that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.
I have a fix for my case:

https://jsfiddle.net/on695rz2/2/

```css
[contenteditable=true]:before {
  content: attr(before-content);
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px">
  <span before-content="4.5" contenteditable="true">Test this simple layout in IE11 and see the wonders of the internet!</span>
</div>
```

This keeps the first part non-editable and the rest editable.

The UX is only good on IE though... so you need to switch implementations accordingly.